# How to display a list of item in tableview when the table did select row at index method is called?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tableview

I have an application in which I have tableview in which I return 3 rows in the tableview. When I select a particular row in the table view another tableview should open which should display list of items and when I select a particular item the value of that particular item should be set to the textlabel of previous tableview.

Comment: what u want exactly? tell me then i help u.

Comment: @Ram i have tableview which contains 3 rows.when i click on the first row i want list of values to be shown in tableview

Comment: is it necessary that the second table be display in same view ?

Comment: @Maulik no it is not neccessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (tableView != secondTableview) {
        self.secondTableviewArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"secondfirst",@"secondSecond",nil];
        [secondTableview reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: UITableview type which is ur second tableview which will show details

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open new table view on click of row then you make new xib file and call like as define in below code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    XMLBooksViewController * xmlBooksViewController = [[XMLBooksViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];
    XMLBooksAppDelegate * appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    xmlBooksViewController.author = [appDelegate.authors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:xmlBooksViewController animated:YES];

    [xmlBooksViewController release];
}
```

In next file you define another table view, so the list or items comes as table view.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the second controller (the one that will appear) a weak reference to the first just before showing it. Once the second view controller has appeared and the user has made the selection (you can catch that in (`-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`), send a message to the first giving the value selected.

The first view controller, then can store the new value, and even dismiss/pop the second.
This can also be achieved, by writing your own delegate protocol, so the first conforms to it, and is the delegate for the second.

Answer (score 0):

Take NSString in second view and use the property.from the first view to second view set the string and in second view use that String

Comment: hi i am totally confused can  u explain me in detail

Comment: if i am correct you are using two views if you select first tableview the content in the cell should be displayed in the second view in label right.....